# facebook custom tabs page redirect

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I have created an custom tab for my Faceboook app page with content as ".aspx" file which is displaying fine with no issues in the content area for that tab. Now, I want to have a button on the first page, on clicking it has to take me to new page. Will this work in FaceBook custom tab content area??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am struggeling with the same issue